# How to pass an HTTP path as a file path for streaming on RTSP via Live555 media server?

Tags: c++, apache, rtsp, live555

I am using Live555 for streaming local video files in .ts format on RTSP using the Live555 media server. It works fine for the local files but I want to stream files hosted on a webserver. In my case, I am using the Apache server to host my files.

When I use the below URL it works fine.

```
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/D:/Recordings/4/12-27-2023/17-51-17.ts
```

But when I use a URL like this it does not work

```
rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/http://127.0.0.1:8732/cam4/DRecordings/4/12-27-2023/17-51-17.ts
```

Here http://127.0.0.1:8732/cam4/DRecordings/4/12-27-2023/17-51-17.ts is the path where my file is hosted.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You need to implement this behaviour, [DynamicRTSPServer.cpp](https://github.com/rgaufman/live555/blob/master/mediaServer/DynamicRTSPServer.cpp) open a local file.